# Нужно ли в корутине писать yield два раза?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал простейшую, в которой выводится сумма двух чисел:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def gen():
    nums = yield 
    yield(nums[0] + nums[1])

g = gen()
g.send(None)
try:
    print(g.send((1, 2)))
except:
    print('----stop')
```

как видите, в ней yield используется два раза.

Далее я попытался переписать корутину так чтобы yield использовался один раз:

```
def gen():
    nums = yield nums[0] + nums[1]

g = gen()
g.send(None)
try:
    print(g.send((1, 2)))
except:
    print('----stop')
```

В результате получил в консоль следующее сообщение об ошибке:

> File "./hello.py", line 16, in gen
>       nums = yield nums[0] + nums[1] UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nums' referenced before assignment

Скажите пожалуйста что сделано не так? Неужели чтобы вернуть один раз результат нужно использовать два раза yield, это нормально?

Я понимаю так:

1. корутина создаётся
2. при первом вызове в ней нужно передать None(в этом случае выполнение дойдёт ДО первого yield)
3. при втором вызове я передаю числа в виде аргумента. в этом случае выполнение начнётся С первого yield и далее. То есть выполнится:

   yield nums[0] + nums[1]

это аналогично

```
return nums[0] + nums[1]
```

Comment: `yield чтототам` возвращает значение `чтототам` наружу. Ваше `чтототам` это `nums[0] + nums[1]`. Но это значение невозможно посчитать, потому что переменной `nums` ещё не существует

Comment: `return sum((yield))` да и всё. Или `yield sum((yield))` если не хочется StopIteration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Дэвид Бизли](https://www.dabeaz.com) не рекомендует смешивать концепции генераторов и сопрограмм:

> - Despite some similarities, Generators and coroutines are basically two different concepts
> - Generators produce values
> - Coroutines tend to consume values
> - It is easy to get sidetracked because methods meant for coroutines are sometimes described as a way to tweak generators that are in the
>     process of producing an iteration pattern (i.e., resetting its value).
>     This is mostly bogus.

Чтобы разобраться с возникающей ошибкой, надо понять последовательность выполнения генераторной функции, в какие именно моменты она отдаёт и принимает управление от вызывающего кода.

1. В момент вызова `next` функция выполняется **до** первого `yield`. На нём она замирает и отдаёт управление вызывающему коду.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В момент выполнения `send` вызывающий код отдаёт управление функции, выполнение которой возобновляется возвратом из того `yield`, на которой она замерла. Он возвращает значение (отправленное из `send`), и происходит присваивание переменной `nums`.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   То есть до возврата из `yield` переменной `nums` не существовало.
3. Элементы `nums` суммируются и передаются в `yield`. Функция опять замирает на нём и отдаёт управление вызывающему коду, в который происходит присваивание полученного значения.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть один вызов `send` взаимодействует с двумя операциями `yield`. Можно сказать, что `send` выполняет код между первым `yield` и вторым. Если раскручивать аналогию, то код между yield'ами подобен функции, принимающей значение в первой строке и возвращающей в последней, а вызов `send` подобен вызову этой функции. Поздравляю, вы только познакомились с концепцией [продолжений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

P.S. Внимательный читатель наверняка заметил, что функция так и залипла на последнем `yield`, строка "Завершение" не будет выведена. Можно вызвать ещё раз `next(g)` или `g.send(None)`, тогда функция снова получит управление, выведет строку и выполнит неявный `return None`, что для интерпретатора будет признаком завершения генератора и он выбросит исключение `StopIteration`. Не самое естественное событие, если генератор не используется в цикле.

В тех случаях, когда генератор использует какие-то ресурсы и ему нужен этап их освобождения, используется обработчик исключения `GeneratorExit` и явное закрытие генератора:

```
def example():
    print('Инициализация')
    nums = yield
    try:
        yield (nums[0] + nums[1])
    except GeneratorExit:
        print('Завершение')
        raise

g = example()
next(g)
v = g.send((1, 2))
g.close()
```

Comment: Отличный ответ, отдаю свою метку вам;^)

Comment: @NotStatilko это не обязательно, мне и голосов хватит :)

Answer (score 0):

Да вроде ничего в этом плохого нет. Первым `yield` ты получаешь в генераторе значение которое было в него же отправлено, а вторым `yield` отдаёшь результат