# Использование yield в функциях-генераторах python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Встречал в функциях-генераторах такой вариант написания:

```
def gen(val):
    return (yield val)
```

чем это отличается от такого варианта:

```
def gen(val):
    yield val
```

Для чего может потребовать дополнительно писать "return"?

Comment: Если вы сделаете `g = gen(345); g.send(None); g.send(чтонибудь)`, то в первом случае выскочит исключение `StopIteration` со значением `чтонибудь`, а во втором случае со значением `None`

Comment: Возможно, вам будет интересен [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950451/204271).

Answer (score 2):

Конкретно этот пример, действительно, различий не создает. Однако они появляются при генерации более 1 значения. Сравните следующие варианты:

C return:

```
def f():
    for i in range(1,5):
        return (yield i)

for i in f():
    print(str(i))

----------------
1
```

Без:

```
def f():
    for i in range(1,5):
        yield i

for i in f():
    print(str(i))

----------------
1
2
3
4
```

Таким образом `return` перед `yield` позволил "остановить" дальнейшую генерацию значений (весь поток выполнения `f()` был остановлен). В определенных случаях это может быть полезно при фильтрации элементов, попадаемых в генератор, например, по условию.

Comment: На самом деле разница есть, см. мой комментарий к вопросу

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за прояснение, об этом было неизвестно

Answer (score 2):

### Зачем нужен return в функциях-генераторах?

Выполнение `return` завершает работу генератора, при попытке получить из генератора очередное значение, будет выброшено исключение `StopIteration`, свидетельствующее о завершении работы.

```
def gen():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    return
    yield 3
```

```
>>> g = gen()
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
2
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

В более ранних версиях python генератор мог иметь только пустой оператор `return`, но с версии Python 3.3 появилась возможность возвращать значение. Оно передается в конструктор исключения `StopIteration`, и может быть получено вызывающей стороной

```
def gen2():
    yield 1
    return "stop"
```

```
>>> g = gen2()
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: stop
```

Если генератор завершается без `return` или с пустым `return`, это будет аналогично выполнению `return None` и последующему выбрасыванию исключения без параметров.

В Python 3.7 запретили выбрасывать `StopIteration` из генератора нарямую (теперь это ведет к ошибке времени выполнения, а не к завершению генератора). Так что `return` остается единственным правильным способом передать дополнительное значение по окончании работы.

### Зачем может понадобиться возвращаемое значение генератора?

Кроме отлова исключения `StopIteration` (напрямую этого обычно никто не делает), это позволяет генератору получать результат работы вложенного генератора

```
def subgen():
    yield 1
    return "ok"

def gen():
    result = yield from subgen()
    return result == "ok"
```

```
>>> g = gen()
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: True
```

### Что именно вернет `return (yield val)`?

`yield` способен не только отдавать значения вызывающей стороне, но и принимать значения от нее с помощью расширенного интерфейса работы с генераторами.

```
def gen():
    x = yield 1
    return f'got {x}'
```

```
>>> g = gen()
>>> g.send(None)
1
>>> g.send(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: got 123
```

Так что результат будет зависеть от переданного значения, но обычно это будет `None`, потому, что `next(g)` для генератора примерно соответствует `g.send(None)`

### Обязательно ли использовать `return` в генераторе?

Нет, особенно если не хотите, чтобы на этой строке выполнение закончилось.

`return (yield val)` это идиома – краткий способ сгенерировать значение и сразу остановить работу генератора, вернув *какое-то* значение, которого скорее всего никто не увидит. Но краткий не всегда значит правильный.